# how to allow to enter special characters in text field in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, special-characters

I have text field with name of account number but it enter only numbers digit I want to write special characters as well like `-` `,` `/` in text field.

This is my form:

```
<?php if($user->userAccountNumber != "") {?>
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('userAccountNumber') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="userAccountNumber">ÄŒÃ­slo ÃºÄtu</label>
        {{ Form::text('userAccountNumber', $user->userAccountNumber, ['class'=>'form-control only-integer','id'=>'userAccountNumber','disabled']) }}
    </div>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('userAccountNumber') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="userAccountNumber">ÄŒÃ­slo ÃºÄtu</label>
        {{ Form::text('userAccountNumber', $user->userAccountNumber, ['class'=>'form-control only-integer','id'=>'userAccountNumber']) }}
    </div>

<?php }?>
```

Please can anyone help to enter special characters into my this text field.
Help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Does it have something to do with setting the class `'form-control only-integer'`?

Comment: I don't know about the css/js part but maybe this class `only-integer` you've attributed to the field is causing this.

Comment: how to change it into special characters?

Comment: The issue must be the class `only-integer`. If you want numbers, letters & special chars, remove it. If you want *only* numbers and those 3 special chars, you'll have to make a class / js yourself or use another masking library.

Answer (score 0):

Its to do with the security settings in laravel it's self. Why did you want special character's as hackers use them to access the data base?

Comment: If you are limiting characters for security you have a security issue with your site.